# Problems with Classic ASP displaying in chrome a PDF document from binary blob

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, asp-classic

I'm using a classic ASP website to search and display PDF files that are stored as binary blobs in a SQL server database. The page works fine in IE and Safari but in Chrome it displays the document as a grey box.

Chrome is using the Chrome PDF viewer plugin as it no longer supports the Adobe one. It all works fine if I change it to point directly at a PDF file on the web server rather than stream the binary blob.

Can anyone suggest why this may be happening?

Comment: You passing back the streamed blob with the correct `Content-Type` HTTP header (`Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"`)? Might help if we could see some code? See [ask]

Comment: Here's the code I'm using:

Comment: Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")      
 With oStream      
  .Type = adTypeBinary      
     .Open      
  If ISNULL(oRecordset.Fields("File")) Then Call ExitAndClose    
     .write    oRecordset.Fields("File").GetChunk(oRecordset.Fields("File").ActualSize)    
     .Position = 0    
 End With    
    
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"    
 Response.BinaryWrite oStream.Read(adReadAll)    
 Response.Flush